# Difference ggplot2 and autoplot() after prcomp?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I made a PCA plot with autoplot(), but I wanted to have ellipses around only 2 of the groups instead of all 3. Therefore I switched to ggplot. However, it seems that my axes are different between autoplot and ggplot methods. Look at the difference between p1 and p2:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
library(tidyr)

x <- iris[1:4]
pc <- prcomp(x)
df <- cbind(pc$x[,1:2], iris[,5]) %>% as.data.frame()
df$PC1 <- as.numeric(df$PC1)
df$PC2 <- as.numeric(df$PC2)
df$V3 <- as.factor(df$V3)

#ggplot method
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(PC1, PC2, colour = V3)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(shape = V3)) +
  stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon", aes(fill = after_scale(alpha(colour, 0))),
               data = df[df$V3 == "1" | df$V3 == "2",], size = 1) 
p1



#autoplot method
y <- prcomp(x)
x2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(x, iris[,5]))
x2$`iris[, 5]` <- as.factor(x2$`iris[, 5]`)

p2<- autoplot(y, 
              data = x2, 
              colour = 'iris[, 5]', 
              label = F, 
              shape = 'iris[, 5]',
              size = 2)

p2


Created on 2022-02-22 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Why do I get different axes?

Comment: I think autoplot scales the PC scores by the variance of the PC, whereas you are plotting the PC scores directly. Or something like that. Piecing PCA together from math articles, pca tutorials, r tutorials and looking at source of implementations is surprisingly not straight-forward and I am still confused myself after days...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the autoplot method, the principal components are scaled, so to get the same result you would do:

```r
x <- iris[1:4]
pc <- prcomp(x)
df <- cbind(pc$x[,1:2], iris[,5]) %>% as.data.frame()
df$PC1 <- as.numeric(df$PC1) / (pc$sdev[1] * sqrt(nrow(iris)))
df$PC2 <- as.numeric(df$PC2) / (pc$sdev[2] * sqrt(nrow(iris)))
df$V3 <- as.factor(df$V3)

#ggplot method
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(PC1, PC2, colour = V3)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(shape = V3)) +
  stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon", aes(fill = after_scale(alpha(colour, 0))),
               data = df[df$V3 == "1" | df$V3 == "2",], size = 1) 
p1
```

[image]